# How to retrieve the XHR parameters after a jQuery Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

In my project I have a column with several filters with jQuery Ajax Calls in order to reduce number of poducts shown in main.php `<div id="target">`. Works fine, but after eg sorting the results or clicking pagination in response file main.php, I need to be able to do a new filter-action in the filter-column with the $_GET parameters of the last Ajax call of `main.php`. These paramaters show up fine in Firebug tab Net - tab XHR - tab Parameters.

But I can't find a way to retrieve the parameters and put them in my function which fires the Ajax call:

```
     function updateStatus(content_show, data) {

     jQuery.ajax({
         method: "get",
         url: content_show,
         data: data,
         beforeSend: function(){
            jQuery("#target").html('<p><img src="images/ajax_load.gif" /></p>');
            }, //show loading just when link is clicked
         success: function(html) {

             // update status element            
            jQuery('#target').show("slow");
            jQuery('#target').html(html);
            }

     });
 }
```

In my filter file I have a function to check and uncheck the checkboxes and start the ajax call:

```
function check_them(obj,URL) {
  var getstr = "";
  var man_id_selected ="";

 for (i=0; i<obj.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++) {
    if (obj.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].type == "checkbox") {

       if (obj.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].checked) {

        getstr = "" + obj.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].name + "=";
        man_id_selected += obj.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value + "_";
       } else {
     <!--     getstr += obj.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].name + "=&";-->
       }
    }

  }
        getUrlStatus('main.php', function(status) { // try to find $_GET parameters of main.php
          alert(status);
           });
  updateStatus(URL, getstr+man_id_selected);    
   }
```

Here I also tried to find the XHR parameters with:

```
 function getUrlStatus(url, callback) {
     jQuery.ajax({
         url: url,
         complete: function(xhr) {
             callback(xhr.status);

         }
     });
 }
```

But the latter off course will only return Status 200 and not the Parameters.

### Edit

After more reading and testing I almost solved the problem by changing my original PHP code and functions for proper formatting of the function updateStatus with a callback:

```
     function updateStatus(url, base_url, new_parameters, old_parameters) {

     jQuery.ajax({
         method: 'get',
         url: base_url,
         data: new_parameters,
         beforeSend: function(){
            jQuery("#target").html('<p><img src="images/ajax_load.gif" /></p>');
            }, //show loading just when link is clicked
         complete: function(){ 
            jQuery("#target").hide("fast");
            }, //stop showing loading when the process is complete


         success: function(html) {
             // update status element            
            jQuery('#target').show("slow");
            jQuery('#target').html(html);
            callback(this.url)
         }
     });
 }
```

Now I only have I slight problem retriving and calling the new url to $url in PHP. I will elaborate on that and possibly post a new topic.

Comment: I'm having difficulty de-cyphering what's being asked here? You obviously have a problem of some kind, but looks like you can't really explain well what the problem is or have solved it already +CLOSE

Comment: I can understand you missed the question, because at time of writing I assumed I was doing something wrong with the Ajax call ... Finally I found the problem was in my PHP code used to trigger the ajax call ... I assume it is off topic to explain my adjustments to the PHP code, but as you can see in the reformatted function updateStatus. I have split the complete url (with all the $_GET parameters in it). Seperate passing of base_url and parameters. Hope this clarifies the solution so far! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

For future reference, if you're using jQuery 1.4+, the success function actually accepts 3 arguments, it's just that the second two are optional and `data` is usually the only one ever needed.

> success(data, textStatus,
>   XMLHttpRequest):Function
>
> A function to
>   be called if the request succeeds. The
>   function gets passed three arguments:
>   The data returned from the server,
>   formatted according to the 'dataType'
>   parameter; a string describing the
>   status; and the XMLHttpRequest object
>   (available as of jQuery 1.4). This is
>   an Ajax Event.

So next time if you need to get more information about the XHR response, you can set up your success function like so:

```
success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    // tests with status and xhr, etc...
}
```

Comment: This may be what he's after. I'm not sure. I still voted your answer up because this may be it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Off course I did a lot of tests with the succes function.  But - as mentioned above - the initial data invoked in the function updateStatus were not correct .. therefore the succes data weren't helping!

Comment: This indicates how to retrieve the `xhr` object, but I think the question was asking about request parameters, which are presumably in a `xhr` property. Any idea which one?